# Open source Java Data Structures Reference needed

Tags: java, open-source

The link http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html describes several interesting data structures like concurrent skip-list. Is there any known reliable open source representation of these?

Comment: Why do you need open source?  Do you need to make changes?

Comment: @Kathy Need to make some design choices, and wanted to look at how things are done in open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [`EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent` package](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html) upon which those classes are based (although this library is in maintenance mode only now).

Of course, you can also have a look at the [OpenJDK source](http://openjdk.java.net/) for a more recent version.